# Cygwin OpenSSH Server Error 1062

Tags: windows, ssh, cygwin, cygwin-sshd

I tried to setup an OpenSSH Server on my Windows machine.
I installed cygwin and the openssh package.
Then configured "ssh-host-conf" an

```
*** Query: Overwrite existing /etc/ssh_config file? (yes/no) yes
*** Info: Creating default /etc/ssh_config file
*** Query: Overwrite existing /etc/sshd_config file? (yes/no) yes
*** Info: Creating default /etc/sshd_config file
*** Info: Privilege separation is set to yes by default since OpenSSH 3.3.
*** Info: However, this requires a non-privileged account called 'sshd'.
*** Info: For more info on privilege separation read /usr/share    
/doc/openssh/READ                                                                      ME.privsep.
*** Query: Should privilege separation be used? (yes/no) yes
*** Info: Updating /etc/sshd_config file

*** Query: Do you want to install sshd as a service?
*** Query: (Say "no" if it is already installed as a service) (yes/no) yes
*** Query: Enter the value of CYGWIN for the daemon: [] ntsec
*** Info: On Windows Server 2003, Windows Vista, and above, the
*** Info: SYSTEM account cannot setuid to other users -- a capability
*** Info: sshd requires.  You need to have or to create a privileged
*** Info: account.  This script will help you do so.

*** Info: You appear to be running Windows XP 64bit, Windows 2003 Server,
*** Info: or later.  On these systems, it's not possible to use the LocalSystem
*** Info: account for services that can change the user id without an
*** Info: explicit password (such as passwordless logins [e.g. public key
*** Info: authentication] via sshd).

*** Info: If you want to enable that functionality, it's required to create
*** Info: a new account with special privileges (unless a similar account
*** Info: already exists). This account is then used to run these special
*** Info: servers.

*** Info: Note that creating a new user requires that the current account
*** Info: have Administrator privileges itself.

*** Info: The following privileged accounts were found: 'cyg_server' .

*** Info: This script plans to use 'cyg_server'.
*** Info: 'cyg_server' will only be used by registered services.
*** Query: Do you want to use a different name? (yes/no) no
*** Query: Please enter the password for user 'cyg_server':
*** Query: Reenter:


*** Info: The sshd service has been installed under the 'cyg_server'
*** Info: account.  To start the service now, call `net start sshd' or
*** Info: `cygrunsrv -S sshd'.  Otherwise, it will start automatically
*** Info: after the next reboot.

*** Info: Host configuration finished. Have fun!
```

When I try to start the sshd Daemon I get an 1062 Error:

```
$ cygrunsrv.exe -S sshd
cygrunsrv: Error starting a service: QueryServiceStatus:  Win32 error 1062:
The service has not been started.
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Run Cygwin using elevated privileges (right click, run as administrator). Then re-run ssh-host-conf.

Comment: Still the same error :-/